# selenium , java , testing

Tags: java, selenium, pdf

How can i skip the error and continue with the next iteration in `for loop` , i have pasted my code below , what I'm trying is , I'm trying to download multiple PDF from a website , i have used the *linkText-FullText PDF* which is available for all the PDF exept one , so the loop fails and program stops .

```
Error: Exception in thread "main"
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Fulltext PDF"}  
(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Isn't the message clear enough ? There exists no element that matches your criteria. Check your code, and the attributes on the page, to see if they match

Comment: String printLink;
        try {
         printLink=d.findElement(By.linkText("Fulltext PDF")).getAttribute("href");
        }
        
        catch (NoSuchElementException  e ) {
         printLink = "no_data_found";
        }

Answer (score 2):

You can use try catch block to skip the error as given below.

```
for(;;){

     try{

          //code to click on link text

    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException ex){

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any looping condition like for, while with try catch to handle exception with continuous execution

while(true or condition here){

```
   try{

       // your code here

   }catch(Exception e){

   }
```

}

or

for(;condition here;){

```
  try{

      // your code here

  }catch(Exception e){

  }
```

}